# Any method or template to write kernel extension for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, kernel-extension

Any method or template available in ios world to write iOS kernel extension?Is it possible to write a kernel extension for iOS. I know we can write kernel extension for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Maybe under a jailbroken situation.